# JS: Function running too fast but don't want to use quick patch of a setTimeout

Tags: javascript

At then of `gestureEnd`, I call `checkInView()` which iterates through the `img` tags and checks to see which is in view.  If it's in view, I shrink it (going to add transitions later).
The problem is `checkInView()` is running too quickly.  I tested this by adding a `setTimeout` for a few seconds before `checkInView()` is run but I removed that because it feels hacky.  Is there another way to resolve this?

```
     function isElementInViewport(el) {
        var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        return rect.bottom > 0 &&
            rect.right > 0 &&
            rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /* or $(window).width() */ &&
            rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) /* or $(window).height() */;
    }

    function checkInView() {
        let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
        for (let x of images) {
            if (isElementInViewport(x)) {
                x.style.height = "99px"
            }
        }
    }

    function goBack() {
        let carouselImagesContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-container');
        carouselImagesContainer.scrollLeft -= carousels[0].clientWidth
    }

    function goForward() {
        let carouselImagesContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-container');
        carouselImagesContainer.scrollLeft += carousels[0].clientWidth
    }
    function gestureEnd(evt2) {
        let endPoint = evt2.changedTouches[0].screenX;
        let total = endPoint - startingPoint;
        if (Math.abs(total) < 50) {
            return;
        }
        if (total > 0) {
            let foo = window.requestAnimationFrame(goBack)
        } else {
            let foo = window.requestAnimationFrame(goForward)
        }
        checkInView()
    }
```

Comment: "which iterates through the img tags and checks to see which is in view" - **don't do that**. Use `IntersectionObserver` instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: well this is pretty neat, didn't know about this.  Thanks

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Create yourself an answer instead or accept one of the existing answers.

Comment: @Yunnosch ok, sorry ..even if I don't know if that is an acceptable solution?

Comment: You can state that in the answer. If it is really bad you will get helpful comments on it (and admittedly possibly downvotes). If it is a bit hacky but otherwise a solution you will be told that, helpfully. Chances are good that you don't lose anything. Otherwise you can learn from it and delete the answer later. In my opinion, mixing the answer into your question is worse (for the purpose of StackOverflow) and more likely to get you downvotes.

Comment: ah my apologies..I always thought when you add your own answer, it chooses that as the accepted answer and essentially closes the question.

Comment: I never heard that. I think it is not the case. I know for example that you explicitly accept your own answer and that you can but do not have to. You could e.g. still accept another answer. And I would see that as constructive contribution to the Q/A page like "I found this myself, but actually that other solution I like even better." It is also one of the reasons of not editing answers into the question, to be able to communicate this detail. If anything undesirable happens with your answer let me know. I will help with anything I lured you into... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution although I don't know if this is an acceptable way: In order to ensure the goBack and/or goForward is complete before I run checkInView(), I used Promise.resolve()

```
function goBack() {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        let carouselImagesContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-container');
        carouselImagesContainer.scrollLeft -= carousels[0].clientWidth
    })
    .then(() => {
        checkInView()
    })
}

function goForward() {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        let carouselImagesContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-container');
        carouselImagesContainer.scrollLeft += carousels[0].clientWidth
    })
    .then(() => {
        checkInView()
    })
}
```

Is this acceptable or a good use case for Promises?

Comment: actually, that solves nothing....just having `checkInView` moved into these functions resolved it so the Promise did nothing.  How can I keep it where it was originally and resolve it synchronously

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous about your code - there's absolutely no need to use `Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use an array of images and a current_id variable, since you're going back and forward what image is in the view is straightforward. Here an example of what you can do:

```
var images = []; // fill this when app is ready?
var current_id = 0; // images[0] is the first image in the carousel

goBack() {
 // other stuff here...
 current_id--;
 images[current_id].style.height = "99px";
}

goForward(){
// other stuff here
current_id++;
images[current_id].style.height = "99px";
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is a good idea.  I know my way is not the ideal way but now I'm bothered with trying to see the solution to my issue first before I scrap it and implement a better way.